# Is there something like a mapcdr function?

Tags: clojure

Clojure's `map` is what other lisps might call `mapcar` with `car` being roughly equivalent to clojure's `first`. This makes me wonder if there is a `mapcdr` and whether clojure has a such a function where `cdr` is roughly equivalent to clojure's `rest`.

I imagine the behavior to be like such:

```
(mapcdr #(apply + %) [1 2 3 4 5])
=> (15 14 12 9 5)
```

The expansion looking like:

```
(list (apply + [1 2 3 4 5])
      (apply + [2 3 4 5])
      (apply + [3 4 5])
      (apply + [4 5])
      (apply + [5])
```

Comment: The correct name is `maplist`. It's the very first higher order function as it's one of the examples in John McCarthy's [original Lisp paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html). After the introduction of `mapcar` (or just `map` in other languages) uses of `maplist` plummeted, but [CL still has it](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fn [reductions](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions), which does almost what you want:

```
(->> [1 2 3 4 5]
     reverse
     (reductions +)
     reverse)
```

Comment: Breaks, versus OP's `listmap`, when `fn` is not communicative for example `-`, and when the `fn` cannot be applied pairwise and reduced, for example `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote something quick, though it'd still be nice to have something more native.

```
(defn maplist
  "Based on Common Lisp's maplist."
  [fn coll]
  (if (empty? coll) nil
      (cons (fn coll)
            (maplist fn (rest coll)))))

(maplist #(apply + %) [1 2 3 4 5])
=> (15 14 12 9 5)
```

I'd be surprised if there isn't because it seems like standard `map` is just `maplist` with `first` wrapped around `coll`.